# I got a little yellow sticker on top right corner of my french identity card, saying 102 A?

Tags: france, paperwork, terminology, french-language

I got a little yellow sticker on top right corner of my french identity card, saying 102 A? Does anyone know what that is?

Comment: drench identity card?

Comment: Could you add a picture of this sticker, remembering to hide all personal details from the id card?

Answer (score 5):

This is probably a batch or sequence number. This is used before the delivery to sort the cards.